# Closure's SeamlessField is covering text with a scrollbar

Tags: contenteditable, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to use Google's Closure library for the HTML editor.  I created a `goog.editor.SeamlessField` but if I enter a word that is too long for the width, it puts a scrollbar in and covers the text.  How do I fix this?

[image: SeamlessField with covered text]

This appears to be happening only in Firefox.  Here is some HTML that demos the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js'></script>
  <script>
  goog.require('goog.dom');
  goog.require('goog.editor.SeamlessField');
  </script>
  <script>
  function init() {
     var d = goog.dom.getElement('div1');
     var f = new goog.editor.SeamlessField(d);
     f.makeEditable();
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<div style='width:150px;'>
<div id='div1'>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</div>
</div>

<button onclick='init();'>Create editor</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may only be happening in Firefox.  Chrome and Safari don't do it.  Don't have IE handy.

Answer (score 0):

DOM fragments generated by this SeamlessField component differ for Chromium and Firefox. The former gets an classic div element, the later issues an iFrame. The scheme has something to do with how Firefox handles content-editable elements. By styling the iFrame, you should be able to avoid the scrollbar.